# Sort two tables by the integer values of one of them

Tags: sorting, printing, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to put the finishing touches on a script, but I can't seem to get table data to print the way I want it to.

I have a table with integers and a table with strings.
The tables are created automatically using a loop; however in my test script I have manually added the indices of the table of strings, while the integer table is still automatically created. Again, in my test script, I'm just using math.random to fill the integer table. I have an "if..then" to skip over any entry of "0" while printing.

What I want is to sort each printed line numerically by the integer in table sc and then print the correlated string from table ctable with it.

For example: the math.random loop creates indices in table sc where sc = {"3","1","10","8","7","10"}
I then want that table to print in descending order with the correct string from ctable.

```
>    Desired print results: 
>     g = 10
>     o = 10
>     b = 8
>     p = 7
>     c = 3
>     w = 1
```

After messing around with table.sort, I just reverted back to my original script (with no sorting) shown below

```
local ctable = {"c","w","g","b","p","o"}  
local sc = {}

for i = 1, 6 do
    local mr = math.random(1,10)
    sc[i] = mr
    if sc[i] <= 0 then
        goto done
    else
        print(ctable[i] .. " = " ..sc[i])
    end
   ::done:: 
   i = i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to associate the random number to the string value.

Using two tables; before a sort the association is the index of the tables:

```
-- index:   1   2   3   4   5   6
local t = {'c','w','g','b','p','o'}
local n = { 3,  1,  10, 8,  7,  10}
```

Lua's `table.sort` takes a comparison function that receives two values, but you need to know the index so you can look in the other table to control the ordering.

You can create a lookup table; a table where the keys are values and the values are indexes:

```
local m = {}
for i, v in ipairs(t) do
  m[v] = i
end

-- m = {c=1, w=2, g=3, b=4, p=5, o=6}
```

Then in the comparison function you can lookup the index by value using `m[a]` or `m[b]`. Use the index to lookup the associated number in `n`:

```
table.sort(t, function(a, b)
    return n[m[b]] < n[m[a]]
  end)
```

This works only when the values in `t` are unique. If the string can repeat then you won't be able to do a lookup table, so you can store everything in one table.

```
local t = {{'c',3},{'w',1},{'g',10},{'b',8},{'p',7},{'o',10}}

table.sort(t, function(a, b)
    return b[2] < a[2]
  end) 

for i, v in ipairs(t) do
    print(v[1]..' = '..v[2])
end

-- o = 10  
-- g = 10  
-- b = 8   
-- p = 7   
-- c = 3   
-- w = 1
```

Lua's `table.sort` isn't stable; from the [Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort):

> The sort algorithm is not stable: elements considered equal by the given order may have their relative positions changed by the sort.

This is why `'g'` and `'o'` are not in the order you might expect.